# Couldn't able to run python script from php

Tags: php, python-3.6

I am using python library 'BS4' for webscraping and will be using php for displaying that output on a webpage.

Using bs4 library to scrape through webpages and I am trying to run that python script without using python library for web-development such as django and flask.
I found out there are answers using "Laravel" but I couldn't figure it out since I am not familiar with "Laravel", so I tried "shell_exec("python Script_name.py")" but I think I am missing something.
The python file and the php file are in the same folder.

Code 1 that I have tried

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('WebScraperAmazon.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Code 2 that I have tried

```
<?php 
    shell_exec('python WebScraperAmazon.py');
?>
```

This is my python code named as "WebScraperAmazon.py"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_url = "https://www.amazon.in/GeForce-DirectX-192-Bit-Graphics-ZT-P10620A-10M/dp/B07L5FPY3C/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=gtx+1060&qid=1572277711&sr=8-1"
headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())
title = soup.find(id ="productTitle").get_text()
print(title.strip())

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
price = price[2:]
price = price.replace(',','')
converted_price = float(price)

print(converted_price)
```

The desired output is to show the price and name of the product that has been scraped on the webpage.

```
ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1060 DirectX 12 6GB 192-Bit GDDR5X Graphics Card (ZT-P10620A-10M)
17400
```

Comment: What happens if you run `python WebScraperAmazon.py` from the command line in the same working directory as where you try to run your PHP script?

Comment: `/path/to/python /path/to/WebScraperAmazon.py`

Comment: when I run the same command in cmd it gives the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PHP is running whatever version of python is installed by default on the server and the PHP user profile has a clean install and therefore no modules installed. It also has limited permissions so it cannot pip install certain modules such as BeautifulSoup.

To best work around this and ensure you do not compromise the PHP profile, setup a virtual environment for you python installation/application ensuring to pip install all required modules.

Now this is done we can call this instance directly to execute the script. You will however need to ensure that home is set in PHP so that it you can use the actual file paths.

```
<?php
// Set the 'HOME' environment variable (replace with the appropriate path)
putenv('HOME=/home/yourusername');

// Execute the Python script
exec("/home/yourusername/virtualenv/application_name/python/3.9/bin/python /home/yourusername/location_of_script/WebScraperAmazon.py", $output, $return_var);

// Check the output and return status once verified this can be edited to just be the expected output
echo "Output: " . implode("\n", $output) . "<br>";
echo "Return Status: " . $return_var;
?>
```

I know this is old but I found it after having the same issue and after a lot of debugging found the answer. This is here for anyone like me who is having the same issue.